# Creating Html report with PieChart in it using C#

Tags: c#, pie-chart

I am working on developing an automation framework to automate a UI. I am trying to add HTML report when I run any testcase and was able to generate an HTML file  using `HTMLReportEngine` class.

But I would also want to add a pie chart to the same HTML file which basically provides an overview of Test conditions passed/ Test conditions failed.

I am not sure if I can able to do that using `HTMLReportEngine` class. Is there any other way to do this?

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Jplot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) (a JavaScript library) for making reports and graph using html and javascript. Its easy to embed in the code and having rich features for drawing charts and graphs.

Comment: Okay. I will do some work around on this Jplot. Thanks.
I will let you know if this works out.